# ZipEntry size is too large

Tags: java, zip

I am reading a file test1.xlsx which has according to Windows:

> Size: 9,71 KB (9 950 bytes)
>
> Size on disk: 12,0 KB (12 288 bytes)

```
InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testData/test1.xlsx");
ZipInputStream test = new ZipInputStream(input);
ZipEntry entry = test.getNextEntry();
System.out.println(entry.getSize());
```

But this code prints 3183472384, which is much larger than actual size.

```
/**
 * Gets the uncompressed size of this {@code ZipEntry}.
 *
 * @return the uncompressed size, or {@code -1} if the size has not been
 *         set.
 */
 public long getSize() {
     return size;
 }
```

What is the reason of this difference?

Comment: Either `ZipEntry.getSize()` is incorrect or Winders is. I suspect the later. Maybe you should research and put some more information into your question.

Comment: 3 MB might be anything, like some good compressable image like an imported .bmp bitmap. Rename the xlsx as .zip and check manually. `getCompressedSize()` is the portion added to the .xlsx. What is the entry name?

Comment: Renamed and extracted. The extracted directory has 56,0 KB (57 344 bytes)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What does the *real* code look like?

Comment: It is real code, it was taken from groovy file so there were no semicolons. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: That's what I was asking for. The real code. What you posted wasn't the real code.